# Type mismatch in object factory

Tags: java, design-patterns

I'm using a very simple factory class to create an initialize some of my objects:

```
   public class MyFactory {
      public static Superclass createObject(String type) {
         Superclass myObject = null;
         if (type.equals("type1")) {
            myObject = new Subclass();
            myObject.setParam("val1");
         }
         return myObject;
      }
   }
```

Not that complex :-) No generic code etc., only this way. Nevertheless I get a type mismatch error in Eclipse if I use my factory this way:

```
Subclass myObj = MyFactory.createObject("type1");
```

The error says that it cannot convert from Superclass to Subclass, but everywhere I look (Heads First Design Patterns etc.) I can see it this way: return as type the superclass of created subclasses... So why do I get this error :-)? Thank you!

Comment: @Vakimshaar yes absolutely :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ***The error says that it cannot convert from Superclass to Subclass***

That's right. It's the same reason you can't store a `Number` in an `Integer` for instance (The `Number` could actually be a `Double`!)

If you *know* that `Subclass` is returned from `ProbeFactory.createProbe("type1")` then you can cast it like this:

```
Subclass myObj = (Subclass) ProbeFactory.createProbe("type1");
```

---

Down-casting should be avoided if possible. Either you design it so that you can do with

```
Superclass myObj = ProbeFactory.createProbe("type1");
```

or you could try to create a type-safe version of the factory:

```
Subclass myObj = ProbeFactory.createSubProbe("type1");
```

Comment: Ok and how to do it correctly? As I said/wrote, I found it only this way, even in my books... where is my misunderstanding?

Comment: Thank you for this explanation, I thought that a type cast is not the best way to do this :-) I'll think about it, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You could explicitely cast the return value to `Subclass` which will fail as soon as the factory returns another `Subclass` of `Superclass` and will throw an exception during runtime. **Therefore, don't do it.**

The more appropriate way would be to declare `myObj` as type `Superclass` and have the interface contain the methods you need. If you need to know the exact subtype that is returned, using a factory pattern is a bit pointless.

Comment: I'll think about it and maybe don't use a factory or a more complex one :-)

Answer (score 0):

It's the other way around. If you get a `SubClass` you can assign it to a `SuperClass` variable (if we assume SubClass extends SuperClass).

Answer (score 0):

As the method returns Superclass you cant directly assign it to a Subclass.

You need to use this or type cast.

```
Superclass myObj = ProbeFactory.createProbe("type1");

Subclass myObj = (Subclass) ProbeFactory.createProbe("type1");
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that will throw "java.lang.ClassCastException: Superclass cannot be cast to Subclass".

Comment: If you know subclass is being returned, it would not.

Comment: But in that case the cast is no longer necessary.

Comment: Subclass myObj = ProbeFactory.createProbe("type1"); is a compilation error - cannot convert from Superclass to Subclass and would not work without casting

Answer (score 0):

Usually you want to treat the objects of the same factory similarly, that is why Superclass is created to have all the common behaviour in. If you really want to use them class specific, then, yes, you should do the cast. But I feel like it kills the purpose of abstract factory.

if you want a specific product or group of products when subclass your factory and receive it from the child factory